# 'uWS/uWS.h' file not found in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, websocket, xcode9

I am attempting to import a **C++ Game Server project** into **`Xcode`**.

But I am running into the following error:

```
'uWS/uWS.h' file not found in XCode
```

I have tried importing the library by dragging it into the project, and ran the following commands to compile the **`uWebSockets`** library in Terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets
cd uWebSockets
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

But am running into this error. I have tried to search for how to resolve this is issue for a couple of hours, but still can't figure it out.

[XCode Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDY4J.png)

Here is my project hierarchy, I have tried to import/add the library in various different ways:

[Project Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLYlE.png)

Prior to using XCode, I would compile my code through terminal by running the following command:

```
g++ -O3 -L/usr/lib64 -std=c++14 src/main.cpp -pthread -lz -luWS -lssl -luv -o main
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When you `sudo make install` the library, *where* is it installed? It doesn't seem to be in any standard location, which means you have to tell the compiler (and IDE) where to find the header (and library) files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I ran sudo make install in the uWebSockets folder in this hierarchy  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLYlE.png where uWS.h is located

Comment: Yes but is the files you install installed *there*? You have to look at the output from `make install` to learn *where* the files are really installed. *Or* configure the build of the library, to install in a specific place (like inside your project). You still have to tell the IDE (though the project settings) *where* the header and libary files are installed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the output from sudo make install was: mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
cp libuWS.dylib /usr/local/lib/
mkdir -p /usr/local/include/uWS
cp src/*.h /usr/local/include/uWS/          -- where in XCode would I need to reference these folders?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried to add them to my library & header search paths http://pasteupload.com/image/usVCu

Comment: I don't know anything about XCode, but in most IDE's there is a tab (or similar) for preprocessor settings, where you can add locations for header files. And also a tab for linker settings where you can add directories and libraries to link with.